# asp.net add value to form method

Tags: asp.net

Basically I want to place a url in the form action method.

The ltlUrl.text value is added on the server side in pageLoad.
How do i use the ltlUrl as the action method?

```
 <form action="<%# ltlurl.text%>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="title" value="test" />
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are populating the text control on code behind, you can simply do this:

```
this.Page.Form.Action = "http://someour";
```

I believe the VB.NET syntax would be:

```
Me.Page.Form.Action = "http://someurl"
```